# Direction Flag DF in the Windows 64-bit calling convention?

Tags: windows, x86-64, calling-convention, eflags

According to the docs I can find on calling windows functions, the following applies:-

> The Microsoft x64 calling convention[12][13] is followed on Windows
>   and pre-boot UEFI (for long mode on x86-64). It uses registers RCX,
>   RDX, R8, R9 for the first four integer or pointer arguments (in that
>   order), and additional arguments are pushed onto the stack (right to
>   left). Integer return values (similar to x86) are returned in RAX if
>   64 bits or less.
>
> In the Microsoft x64 calling convention, it's the caller's
>   responsibility to allocate 32 bytes of "shadow space" on the stack
>   right before calling the function (regardless of the actual number of
>   parameters used), and to pop the stack after the call. The shadow
>   space is used to spill RCX, RDX, R8, and R9,[14] but must be made
>   available to all functions, even those with fewer than four
>   parameters.
>
> The registers RAX, RCX, RDX, R8, R9, R10, R11 are considered volatile
>   (caller-saved).[15]
>
> The registers RBX, RBP, RDI, RSI, RSP, R12, R13, R14, and R15 are
>   considered nonvolatile (callee-saved).[15]

So, I have been happily calling kernel32 until a call to `GetEnvironmentVariableA` failed under certain circumstances. I finally traced it back to the fact that the direction flag `DF` was set and I needed to clear it.

I have not up till now been able to find any mention of this and wondered if it was prudent to always clear it before a call.

Or maybe that would cause other problems. Anyone aware of the conventions of calling in this instance?

Answer (score 3):

Windows assumes that the [direction flag](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7td56tzs(v=vs.140).aspx) is cleared. Despite in article said about *C* run-time only, this is true for whole windows (I think because windows code itself is primarily written in c/c++). So when your programme begins to execute - you can assume that *DF* is 0. Usually you do not need to change this flag. However if you temporarily change it (set it to 1) in some internal routine you must clear it by *cld* before calling any windows API or any external module (because it assumes that *DF* is 0).

All windows interrupts at very beginning of execution clear *DF* to 0 - so it is safe to temporarily set *DF* to 1 in own internal code, main - before any external call reset it back to 0.

Comment: You also need to make sure DF is clear before your function returns.